# Replace a few substrings in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

Suppose I need to replace few patterns in a string :

```
val rules = Map("abc" -> "123", "d" -> "4", "efg" -> "5"} // string to string
def replace(input:String, rules: Map[String, String] = {...}

replace("xyz", rules)       // returns xyz
replace("abc123", rules)    // returns 123123
replace("dddxyzefg", rules) // returns 444xyz5
```

How would you implement `replace` in Scala ? How would you generalize the solution for `rules : Map[Regex, String]` ?

Answer (score 5):

It's probably easier just to go straight to the general case:

```
val replacements = Map("abc".r -> "123", "d".r -> "4", "efg".r -> "5")

val original = "I know my abc's AND my d's AND my efg's!"

val replaced = replacements.foldLeft(original) { (s, r) => r._1.replaceAllIn(s, r._2) }
replaced: String = I know my 123's AND my 4's AND my 5's!
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Looks like looping over all replacements and call `replaceAll`for each of them. Is it optimal performance/complexity-wise?

Comment: I don't think there's a straightforward alternative. If all the replacement targets had the same replacement string, you could combine the target patterns with the `|` regex operator and do a single `replaceAllIn`. Otherwise, there's nothing simple I can think of. But unless you have gobs of replacemens in your `Map` or the multi-replace will happen in an "inner loop," the performance probably won't be a problem.